# DataFormatString rounding decimal to larger value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, decimal, rounding

`DataFormatString="{0:F2}"` in my ascx page for value **0.0001** results in "**0.00**" and what I need is "**0.01**", that is rounding away from zero. Is it possible to achieve in asp.net with DataFormatString or should I use some custom rounding method?

Comment: .01 is 100 times larger than .0001.

Comment: It is indeed so. But 0.0001 is greater than 0.00 and I want to round 0.0001 to larger value, minimum of which is 0.01 due to {0:F2} formatting string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot achieve this by any kind of rounding. 0.0001 in 2 digits will always become 0.00 .

If you really want this you'll need to write a conversion method. Write out the specs first.

DataFormatString suggests a data-bound control so you may need an extra (computed) column with something like  `r = (v < 0.01 && r > 0.0) ? 0.01 : v;`

Comment: +1 - sounds like OP wants to show underflow on screen (e.g. "< 0.1")

Comment: I've added a code above to my OnRowCreated handler, works nice

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
float fno=2.67f;
int no=Convert.ToInt32(fno);

//using Math.Round Function
decimal d=Math.Round(Convert.Toint64(fno));

//if we want after point 2 decimal then
decimal d=Math.Round(Convert.Toint64(fno),2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Formats a number using a format string without rounding.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <param name="formatString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Format(object value, string formatString)
        {
            double val;

            if (!Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val))
            {
                return "";
            }

            // Special handling for decimals
            if (formatString.Contains("."))
            {
                int multiplier = (int)Math.Pow(10, getDecimalPlaces(formatString) + 1);

                // Handle percentage
                if (!formatString.Contains('%'))
                {
                    multiplier /= 100;
                }

                return (Math.Truncate(val * multiplier) / multiplier).ToString(formatString); // prevent rounding by truncating
            }

            return val.ToString(formatString);
        }
```